# Problem with mdframed and xepersian

Tags: mdframed

When i use `mdframed` in latin mode, it works. but when i use package `xepersian` then it dose not show anythings.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{xepersian}

\begin{document}

\begin{latin}
\begin{mdframed}
This is test.
\end{mdframed}
\end{latin}


\begin{mdframed}
این یک تست است.
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this option for package `mdframed`:

```
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
```

and solved my problem.

[image]

Thank @Vafa for developing `bidi` and thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very obvious. `mdframed` is not supported by `bidi` package and `bidi` package will not be developed any more unless there is some donations to the project. So I am afraid you are on your own to fix your problems from now on. An option would be to use `framed` package instead `mdframed` package.

Also see [`bidi` repository on github](https://github.com/vafa/bidi); you may like to submit a bug report.